# Not able to std::shuffle?

Tags: c++, random, stdvector

[Code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b61a2c417e9d53a2) is basic:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> mSet = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    auto timeSeed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::seed_seq ss{ uint32_t(timeSeed & 0xffffffff), uint32_t(timeSeed >> 32) };
    std::mt19937_64 rng;
    std::shuffle(mSet.begin(), mSet.end(), rng);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < mSet.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << mSet[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

It always show to me the same sequence. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you instantiated `rng`, you did not use `ss`. As such your seed is not used and the sequence will always be the same.

Looks like you meant:

```
std::mt19937_64 rng{ss};
```

<strike>Your compiler should be warning you that `ss` is unused. Do you have warnings turned off for some reason?</strike> Unfortunately GCC does not seem to warn about this even with `-Wextra`.

Comment: By the way, Coliru caches so repeatedly re-running the same snippet will not change the output even with this fixed.